# pop up background not covering navigation bar

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

How to fix the navigation bar visibility when my popup form is appears mean when popup form appears then navigation bar functionality is disabled not for use. Is it possible in angular and typescript. If possible then how can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the code that you currently have so we can see exactly what you need, as from the question it's pretty unclear. It may be doable with CSS, if I understood well what you need.

Comment: On button click I've pass the pointer event class in angular. How its possible ?